# Google Earth Engine nomalization function in python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to normalize data using the following function but i get an error that image collection does not have .multiply

```
def normalization_100(image,region,scale):
  mean_std = image.reduceRegion( ee.Reducer.mean()
            .combine(ee.Reducer.stdDev(),None, True),region,
  scale= scale,
  maxPixels = 10e9,
  tileScale= 16)
  
  def unit_(name):
      name = ee.String(name);
      band = image.select(name);
      mean=ee.Number(mean_std.get(name.cat('_mean')));
      std=ee.Number(mean_std.get(name.cat('_stdDev')));
      max=mean.add(std.multiply(3))
      min=mean.subtract(std.multiply(3))
      band1=ee.Image(min).multiply(band.lt(min)).add(ee.Image(max).multiply(band.gt(max))).add(band.multiply(ee.Image(1).subtract(band.lt(min)).subtract(band.gt(max))))
      result_band=band1.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min));
      return result_band#.toBands().rename(image.bandNames());

  
    

# // use unit scale to normalize the pixel values
  unitScale = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(image.bandNames().map(unit_))#.multiply(10)
  
  return unitScale.multiply(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do band math on collections, only images.
You would need to map a function over the collection, applying the scaling to each image.

```
return unitScale.map(function(img) { return img.multiply(100) })
```